# Fix view ajax load more button

Tags: views, ajax

I have a view with a custom filters form, which is submitted via AJAX.
In the AJAX callback function, I am setting some arguments to the view and render it manually:

```
$view = views_get_view('products_gallery');
$view->set_display('page'); 
$view->set_arguments($url_args);
$view->execute();
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-products-gallery', $view->render());
```

The results come back OK, but the load more button does not work and points to `system/ajax?page=1`.

How can I fix the load more button so that it points to the current page and it loads the next results?

Comment: Have you tried setting the active path before you build your view? ex: `menu_set_active_item("node/$nid")`

Comment: Are you using Views load more? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more

Comment: @thumbson That seems to make the button point to the right url, but now the problem is it's not using AJAX.
Yes, f0ns, I am using the views_load_more module.

Comment: You might also try doing a form alter to change the action of the filter form